# getting distinct value from a list of type comment

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, class, distinct

```
    List<Comment> StreamItemComments = objStreamItem.GetComments();
```

...

```
    foreach (Comment Item in StreamItemComments)
        {
            if (ClientUser.UserName != Item.Sender)
            {
                Notification notificationObj = new Notification
                {
                    Sender = ClientUser.UserName,
                    Recipient = Item.Sender,
                    Value = "whatever value here",
                    TrackBack = "",
                    IsRead = false
                };
                notificationObj.Add();
            }
        }
```

What if there are two 'username' in List in Item.Sender. I'd like to send a notification once to the user. Here if there are duplicate usernames it will send two notifications because i am not filtering out duplicate Item.Senders from the list in StreamItemComments.

Comment: Please don't just add "c#" to your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I'll make sure not to add something like that in the future. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider writing a query to state your intentions. You want the distinct senders of the item comments, but only where the sender is not the client user. Sounds like a query, does it not?

```
var recipients = StreamItemComments
                    .Where(item => item.Sender != ClientUser.UserName)
                    .Select(item => item.Sender)
                    .Distinct();
```

You can then use this query to build your notifications

```
foreach (var item in recipients)
{
    var notificationObj = new Notification
    {
         Sender = ClientUser.UserName,
         Recipient = item,
         ...
    }

    notificationObj.Add();
}
```

You could also fit this object construction into the query, as well, but with your `.Add()` invocation on each object, I left it out of the query. It wouldn't be difficult to incorporate, although you'd still need to loop over the output and invoke `.Add()` for each result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `HashSet` to determine if you already handled a username.

```
var set = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (var item in collection)
{
    if (set.Contains(item))
        continue;

    set.Add(item);

    // your notification code
}
```

For your concrete problem, `set` would contain usernames (`Item.Sender`). So you may want to change the `Add()` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.Distinct()`. Since you can't use the default comparer, you can implement one like this

```
class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Comment>
{
    public bool Equals(Comment x, Comment y)
    {
        return x.Sender.Equals(y.Sender);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Comment obj)
    {
        return obj.Sender.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And then just filter them like this. You don't need the `if` statement.

```
List<Comment> StreamItemComments = objStreamItem.GetComments()
    .Distinct(new MyEqualityComparer())
    .Where(x => x.Sender != ClientUser.UserName)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is in the

```
foreach ( Comment item in StreamItemComments)
```

add every notification to a `Dictionary<user,msg>`

and have another foreach `key` in **[Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)** afterwards loop to send the actual  message to user. This will ensure that only one message per user is sent out

Comment: I thought about something similar to your solution. But what I'm trying to do (if possible somehow) is to directly filter out duplicates from List<Comment> with something like .Distinct() or whatever. thanks tho